# Why can't an emitter go past 200 frames

Tags: rendering, video

I want to make a cover for a preview of my first animation, so in he middle of my animation video, I put all the models in the main set to make a cover for the video, and grabbed one of the cameras.

However when I render it, it just shows the render of the last frame I did on the animation. Its like Blender doesn't want to shoot the cover and just wants to get back to the animation.

Comment: How is the title related to the question? Your objects are animated so probably keyframed, so when you render them they revert to the animated position at that time, rather than the random place you temporarily overridden them to.

Comment: I forgot to change the title. Sorry

Comment: It is not too late to fix it

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly:
By default, in your particle system the particles emit from frame 1 to frame 200. 
Try to increase the "End" value.

[image: particle properties]